# Informatica | Update table with two primary keys

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

If target table has three columns as primary key, but you want to update the same table through informatica using only two columns from those primary key column?

How can we achieve this?

Comment: Just clarify: for each pair of values in your source, you want to update all records in your target that match those 2 source values?

Comment: 1. you can disconnect the 3rd key in target. infa will automatically update based on two keys. 2. You can modify infa target definition and change those 2 columns as combo key and remove 3rd column from combo key. But this is not recommended because you can accidentally update wrong data in that 3rd key column.